# LeJOS NXT Programming

Tags: java, eclipse, nxt

iam a beginner in Programming and trying to make a Cleaning Robot NXT 
i attached ( Ultrasonic Sensor) ,and ( Sound Sensor ) 
the job of the Robot is that when i Clap it have to start moving Forward and when the UltraSonic Sensor sees Something on the way it must turns around  and keep going Forward .
The Problem is that when it turns it doesn't keep moving Forward till i clap again !!!!!

and this is the code that i wrote :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  TouchSensor touch = new TouchSensor(SensorPort.S2);

  SoundSensor sound = new SoundSensor( SensorPort.S4 );

  UltrasonicSensor sonic = new UltrasonicSensor( SensorPort.S3);

  Motor.A.setSpeed( 400 );
  Motor.C.setSpeed( 400 );
  Button.waitForAnyPress();

  int SoundValue;
  SoundValue = sound.readValue();
  System.out.print(SoundValue);

  do {
    if ( sound.readValue() > 50 ) {
      // PROBLEM:       
      while ( sonic.getDistance() > 30 ){
        Motor.B.backward();
        Motor.A.backward();
        Motor.C.backward();
      }
      {
        Motor.A.rotate( -185, true );
        Motor.C.rotate( 185, true );    
      }  
    };
  }

  while( Button.readButtons() != Button.ID_ESCAPE );
}
```

Can any one help solving this Problem please?????

thnx Any way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The think the loop is slightly wrong...

Basically, I think you need a flag to indicate that the bot should be moving, so that when you clap, it flips the flag...

```
boolean move = false;
do {
    if ( sound.readValue() > 50 ) {
        move = !move;
    }

    while ( sonic.getDistance() > 30 ){
        Motor.B.backward();
        Motor.A.backward();
        Motor.C.backward();
    }
    if (move) {
        Motor.A.rotate( -185, true );
        Motor.C.rotate( 185, true );   
    }
} while( Button.readButtons() != Button.ID_ESCAPE );
```

Or something similar.  Otherwise, it will only move when there is another sound

I'd also just like to say, I'm very jealous ;)

Comment: Essentially, it's move = not move, when applied to a boolean value, it flips it from true to false and back again